# Jquery add immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i want to achive using jquery is to add dinamically some elements in the html and the use them after the add. Is this possible ?

```
$.each(myarray, function(index, elm){
newHtml += '<div id="name'+index+'"><h2>'+elm+'</h2></div>';
});

$('#names').html(newHtml);

alert($('#name01').html());
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3s5wo8e/)

Comment: What are your trying to achieve. Please explain

Comment: There is no leading zero in the div names. its just `name1`.

Comment: So you are trying to add more elements?

Comment: if you check your code, The id if the Div would be `name1` and not `name01`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element with id "#name01". Use `alert($('#name1').html());` instead of `alert($('#name01').html());`

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in you code:

```
var n = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) {
alert("name = " + i);
```

}

Try this.. Its may helps you

Answer (score 0):

use `#name1` on your jQuery selector and to grab the text content, use jQuery method `text()` to get just the text content or `html()` to get the whole HTML content.

```
$('#name1').text()
// "name1"

$('#name1').text()
// "<h2>name1</h2>"
```